# Display a layer stored in GeoServer with Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, javascript, leaflet, wms

I wanted to display a layer stored in GeoServer with Leaflet, I used this code but it's not working.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([4.477411, 21.309284], 3);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
{ 
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>' 
})
addTo(map);

// Instantiation de différentes couches provenant de GeoServer

var exemple = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms", {
    layers: 'nurc:Arc_Sample',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true
});

exemple.addTo(map);
```

The error reported is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
```

Comment: Is the debug console in your browser showing any errors?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined

Comment: Make sure you are actually including the Leaflet library inside a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `leaflet.js` and `leaflet.css` files to your project:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>leaflet application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. press f12, resolve any issue visible in the browser-console.
2. disable all other libs/packages of javascript to see any cross lib issue.
3. clear browser cache by using ctrl + f5.
4. if still happening try to use the latest leaflet package and then reload after clear cache.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined`, is more fundamental than CORS being enabled (or not) in the service.

Comment: understood the answer updated.